# SQL Server 2008 - Attach mdf without log - Operating system error 5: 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2008

I am trying to attach database without log file.

[Attach a SQL Server database with a missing transaction log file](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1894/attach-a-sql-server-database-with-a-missing-transaction-log-file/)

**Error on SSMS**

[image]

**Error on TSL**

> Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 1 Unable to open the physical file
>   "....mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".

I'm not sa, but I'm in sysadmin role. I'm not really sure what access permission I need. Or is it because the `.mdf` is corrupted?

[image]

Thank in advance!

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in that link including removing the log file that shouldn't be found (because you made sure it doesn't exist)?

Comment: If you have UAC enabled and are you running SSMS with an administrator token or with your limited privileges token? SQL Server should be doing everything in the context of its service account, but I've been bitten in the ass by UAC anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a bug in the SSMS interface. It can be done using T-SQL. Just don't include the log file in the list of files.

```
exec sp_attach_db 'dbname', 'filename'
```

[sp_attach_db (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Start SQL Server manager as Administrator (right-click on the program, choose "Start as administrator"): problem solved!